# Having problems implementing horizontal cards from materialize css library

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using the Materialize Css library to make a website, but I couldn't successfully add a Horizontal card using the following code, which is exactly the same as shown their guideline from the link below:
http://materializecss.com/cards.html

```
<div class="col s12 m7">
<h2 class="header">Horizontal Card</h2>
<div class="card horizontal">
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/190/nature/6">
  </div>
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <a href="#">This is a link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The card would still be shown as a vertical card.
Any ideas on what the problem could be? I would provide more information if needed..

Answer (score 1):

Allen Hu Please refer the below code.

```
CSS:
    .card.horizontal {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }

HTML:
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m4">
                <h2 class="header">Horizontal Card</h2>
                <div class="card horizontal">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/190/nature/6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-stacked">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is what I got, still not working though :(
http://imgur.com/a/lU6Xx

Comment: Please share the website link

Comment: http://club.ckcsc.info/CLUB.php?page=tryCard
things are in chinese though

Comment: .card.horizontal {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
Use the css

Comment: This definitely solved the problem, thanks for your help!